# ta75m - has vga port but no onboard video?

Tags: motherboard

Can anyone explain how [this motherboard](https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813138333&RandomID=67352241411055920110906093734) has the video out ports (VGA/DVI), but no onboard graphics?  If I purchase this motherboard, will I also need a graphics card?

Comment: I can explain how this isn't the right site for you, please read our FAQ next time.

Answer (score 2):

You get the graphics from the integrated controller on the AMD Llano chips. I'm running a TA75M with an AMD A8-3850 now, using the DVI connector to my display. The graphic engine is not as powerful as current top-end cards, but still very good - and you can use a compatible graphics card in combination with the Llano APUs.

I think this is a great way of doing things. I get high quality graphics without the power and cost overhead of a separate card.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy an A series processor it does include 3d accelerated graphics, full video hardware acceleration, and OpenCL acceleration for programs like Photoshop CS6.

I've got an A6-3670K and this motherboard and I can play Left4Dead 2 at 1920x1080 with all settings maxed out and Portal 2 with everything maxed out but filtering and antialiasing.

Answer (score 0):

It means, it's like a server. You get basic display of what is on the screen, but no graphics acceleration. You won't be able to play any games but DOS maybe. But for configuring and installing stuff, it's fine. Only if you need good graphics would you need to purchase a real card.